# Capitalizing text into a website title

Tags: php, html, styles, title, capitalize

I have a text coming from a sql db that is not capitalized.

In my HTML, I usually apply CSS text-transform to capitalize the text, but now I face an issue:

I want this text to be part of the title of my site. However, I cannot style within the title.

How could I style the text, then grab it on PHP and then plug it into my title?

Here is what I tried which did not work:

```
<title>Shop - <p style="text-transform:capitalize;"><?php echo $row2['name'];?></p></title>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP functions [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php), [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php), [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) depending on what you need.

```
ucfirst($row2['name']);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use PHP transformation.

```
<?php echo ucfirst($row2['name']); ?>
```

There are quite a few functions you can use for this, [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php), [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php), [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php).

As [W3C notes](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/TITLE.html), you should only use text, and with a max length of 64 characters:

> The title is not part of the text of the document, but is a property of the whole document. It may not contain anchors, paragraph marks, or highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a few functions to capitalize text:

```
ucwords($text)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

```
strtoupper($text)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
ucfirst($row2['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this function in php to echo your text in uppercase:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php